# SSO registration different ways to ask for account name

Tags: design-patterns, registration, enterprise

I'm creating a user portal to manage Dongle Licenses with Single Sign-on for a niche 3D Cad software.
We have both single users "B2C" and companies "B2B"

Business rules cannot change now, such as:

- No team plans, but we will allow teams because they already exist
- We use security dongles sold via international dealers that need to be inserted in the user license portal
- All accounts need to have some sort of ID during registration, so all users have "company" or what we call "accounts"
- Accounts can be a single user or companies which can invite teams,
  despite not having a separate team feature.
- I'm short on resources, so I can't do something like Unity 3D does, to "insert organization" into the account.

**Option 1:**

[image]

Problem: the user might think that he needs a company to register

**Option 2:**

Put a radio button for the user to select on registration either company or single user

If the user selects "single user", it grabs First+Last name as the account name

[image]

So if a company is chosen, then it pulls the input field:
[image]

**Option 3:**

Ask for the Account Name

[image]

Problems: if a user is part of the company, it might not know that he/she is supposed to use a correct company here, creating a problem for marketing.

We do have the option on our store which is a separate portal (when a user buys the dongle from us) to pull and confirm this account name and we display as a company on final checkout so the user can correct the name if needed:
[image]

However, that is not an option when the dongles are sold via dealers.

Question:
What is the best way to handle this type of registration from these options, or are there other options?

Is a UX bad and software engineering practice for SSO to ask for account or company name in registration? in most cases I see SSOs asking for just name, email and password.

Comment: Err is this a real person's name and phone number in your screenshot?

Comment: Can you clarify whether multiple individual users within the same company are supposed to go through this flow? Or is there one user within the company who goes through this flow and then others in the company can use the software too?

Comment: 1-Not real data. 
2-In the user portal I can invite team member which triggers the SSO invite via email and the account becomes child of the company/account that invited. In that case account name is not necessary. If the user had originally a demo account (registered via SSO), if he/she gets invited by a team, then its original account name/company gets overridden and it becomes child of company that invited. If a user is already owner of a dongle, it cannot be invited to another team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. So you are dealing with a registration where there are two kinds of users:

- Users who should register as a company
- Users who should register as individuals

And, restating the problems with the options you noted, you want to basically make sure that:

- Users who should register as a company do so, otherwise they won't be able to invite others in the company
- Users who should register as an individual aren't mislead into thinking that they need a company name to register.

I would note that this constraint makes your needs significantly different from most registration flows out there, so looking for inspiration outside is going to be of limited help.

Additionally, because you are targeting a set of users who have already overcome significant hurdles (they have gone through the trouble of purchasing dongles, for example) it should be OK to add a step.

My advice would be to use the [wizard design pattern](https://uxplanet.org/wizard-design-pattern-8c86e14f2a38) for your registration flow:

1. Ask the user to choose between two options with two large buttons:

   - **Register as an individual** 
      Choose this option if you will be using our software by yourself.
   - **Register as a company** 
      Choose this option if others at your company will be using our software.
2. The actual registration form. Depending on the previous step, the "Company" field will or will not be filled out.
3. Confirmation

Alternatively, you can make variants on your options to tactically address the concerns you raised:

For your "option 1", use the [helper text](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#anatomy) design pattern below the input to dispel the risk of misunderstanding by clarifying "You don't need a company to register" or "Only needed if you will invite others within your company to use our software"

For your "option 2", change the label on the "Company" radio button to "Company (choose this if more than 1 person at your company will use the software)" to make it clear that it's important to click Company in order to invite others.

I would not consider "option 3" which feels likely to confuse both individual and company users.

Comment: @DanielVianna glad it helps